R convert column name to rows with some formatting
I am looking at converting the raw table below into something where the column with the subjects names become rows themselves in a new column called Subject.
Raw data:



ID
Year
Math_sub
Eng_sub
Chem_sub




1
2010
20
15
12


1
2015
17
20
14


1
2016
13
17
12


3
2015
14
13
NA


3
2016
12
12
NA


5
2010
20
15
13


5
2015
17
20
14


5
2016
NA
17
12


9
2015
14
13
NA


9
2016
15
15
16



with many more random IDs.
Desired output:



ID
Year
Math_sub
Eng_sub
Chem_sub
Subject




1
2010
20
NA
NA
Maths


1
2010
NA
15
NA
English


1
2010
NA
NA
12
Chemistry


1
2015
17
NA
NA
Maths


1
2015
NA
20
NA
English


1
2015
NA
NA
14
Chemistry


1
2016
13
NA
NA
Maths


1
2016
NA
17
NA
English


1
2016
NA
NA
12
Chemistry


3
2015
14
NA
NA
Maths


3
2015
NA
13
NA
English


3
2015
NA
NA
NA
Chemistry


3
2016
12
NA
NA
Maths


3
2016
NA
12
NA
English


3
2016
NA
NA
NA
Chemistry



I tried a lot of approaches using both the reshape and tidyr library but they are producing an output which is completely miles away from what I need.
Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

One approach could be to pivot longer, add a distinguishing feature to each row (eg row number), and then pivot wider again:
library(tidyverse)
dd |>
  pivot_longer(3:5) |>
  mutate(row = row_number(), subject=sub("_sub$", "", name)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

(h/t @MrFlick for the reminder to add the subject column to match OP request.)
Result
      ID  Year   row subject Math_sub Eng_sub Chem_sub
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>      <int>   <int>    <int>
 1     1  2010     1 Math          20      NA       NA
 2     1  2010     2 Eng           NA      15       NA
 3     1  2010     3 Chem          NA      NA       12
 4     1  2015     4 Math          17      NA       NA
 5     1  2015     5 Eng           NA      20       NA
 6     1  2015     6 Chem          NA      NA       14
 7     1  2016     7 Math          13      NA       NA
 8     1  2016     8 Eng           NA      17       NA
 9     1  2016     9 Chem          NA      NA       12
10     3  2015    10 Math          14      NA       NA
# ℹ 20 more rows


This is an usual transformation. These steps can generate the same data if you aren't too picky about row and column order.
library(dplry)
library(purrr)

subjects <- select(dd, ends_with("_sub"))  %>% names()

map_df(subjects, 
  ~select(dd, ID, Year, all_of(.x)) |> mutate(Subject=sub("_sub$","", .x)))

We grab all the subject columns, loop over them extracting only the matching column and add a column with the name without "_sub". And then we let map_df put all the subsets back together in a single frame and add in the NA values for us.
Tested with
dd <- data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L), 
    Year = c(2010L, 2015L, 2016L, 2015L, 2016L, 2010L, 2015L, 2016L, 2015L, 2016L), 
    Math_sub = c(20L, 17L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 20L, 17L, NA, 14L, 15L),
    Eng_sub = c(15L, 20L, 17L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 20L, 17L, 13L, 15L),
    Chem_sub = c(12L, 14L, 12L, NA, NA, 13L, 14L, 12L, NA, 16L)
)

